# Is there a way to detect audio frequency in HTML 5 web audio API?

Tags: html, html5-audio

I would like to know is there a way we can detect audio frequency from microphone in html 5 web audio. I wish to make an online guitar tuner, and I need to have the audio frequency in hertz, from the sound input. I've seen some EQ and filters effects, but I didn't see anything about frequency recognition.

EDIT:
I found this: http://www.smartjava.org/content/exploring-html5-web-audio-visualizing-sound
The 2nd point (analyser node) is really interesting. I seen his source code, but I can't figure how to connect the analyser to the microphone input.
He calls a playSound() function when the mp3 file starts to play, and there he draws his canvas. But I do not have a playSound() like function...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a web audio library which, among other things, can detect frequency from mic input.  Check it out at https://github.com/rserota/wad#pitch-detection

```
var voice = new Wad({source : 'mic' });
var tuner = new Wad.Poly();
tuner.add(voice);
voice.play();

tuner.updatePitch() // The tuner is now calculating the pitch and note name of its input 60 times per second. These values are stored in tuner.pitch and tuner.noteName.

var logPitch = function(){
    console.log(tuner.pitch, tuner.noteName)
    requestAnimationFrame(logPitch)
};
logPitch();
// If you sing into your microphone, your pitch will be logged to the console in real time.

tuner.stopUpdatingPitch(); // Stop calculating the pitch if you don't need to know it anymore.
```

Comment: I'll test it tonight, when i'll be back home ! It seems to be exacly what I was looking for ! Thanks Raphael !

Comment: I've got a problem with the example. I opened an issue. I'll give you some news when it will be working.

Comment: It's not just you. The example has a problem. Thanks for opening the issue on github. We can continue troubleshooting over there.

Comment: It works ! And it's damn efficient and simple with your lib ! Great work Raphael !

Comment: This is awesome. I'd up vote this twice if I could. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [`BiquadFilterNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode).

Example code from the link:

```
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var biquadFilter = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();
biquadfilter.getFrequencyResponse(myFrequencyArray,magResponseOutput,phaseResponseOutput);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but after testing it, it seems that it just returns the level for a given frequency, and not the live main frequencies. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get the frequencies from the mic.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true}).then(function(localStream){
  var audioContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  var input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(localStream);
  var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
  var scriptProcessor = audioContext.createScriptProcessor();
  // Some analyser setup
  analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0;
  analyser.fftSize = 64;

  input.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(scriptProcessor);
  scriptProcessor.connect(audioContext.destination);
  var getAverageVolume  =  function( array){
      var length = array.length;
      var values = 0;
      var i = 0;
     for (; i < length; i++) {
        values += array[i];
     }
    return values / length;
  };
  var onAudio = function(){
    var tempArray = new window.Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(tempArray);
    var latestFrequency = (getAverageVolume(tempArray));
    //use latestFrequency
  };
  scriptProcessor.onaudioprocess = onAudio;
})
.catch(function(){
  //Handle error
});
```

Comment: I am trying to detecting a beeping and convert it to 0 and 1. And it works great! But if the beeping is fast the browser freezes for like a sec time to time. Do you know how fix that?